# Regex expression to check if a string only contains digits and operators (but no 2 consecutive operators)

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to check if a user-entered string is a valid expression:

1. There can't be any letters [a-zA-z]
2. We're only dealing with integers
3. Spaces are allowed
4. The only valid operators are '+', '-', and '*' (no dividing)
5. There can't be two consecutive operators (so "123 ++ 456" would be invalid)
6. An operator must be followed by digits ("123 + " would be invalid but "345678 * 6" would be okay)

So far my current code `userInput.matches("[0-9(+*\\-\\s)]+")` can process requirements 1-4. How can I modify my regex to meet criteria 5 and 6?

Comment: Use `userInput.matches("\\s*\\d+(?:\\s*[-+*]\\s*\\d+)*\\s*")`

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code:

```
bool valid = userInput.matches("\\d+(?:\\h*[+*-]\\h*\\d+)*");
```

If you want to allow signed `-` numbers then use:

```
bool valid = userInput.matches("-?\\d+(?:\\h*[+*-]\\h*-?\\d+)*");
```

If there can be leading/trailing spaces then use:

```
bool valid = userInput
   .matches("\\h*-?\\d+(?:\\h*[+*-]\\h*-?\\d+)*\\h*");
```

**Breakup:**

- `\\d+`: Match 1+ digits
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `\\h*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
  - `[+*-]`: Match `+` or `*` or `-`
  - `\\h*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
  - \d+`: Match 1+ digits
- `)*`: End non-capture group. Repeat this group 0 or more times